# How to run pytest files in same browser one after another with the resulted url from the previous test

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I have various pytest files like signup, login, registration, exam registration, I want to signup and in that resulted page I need to run login file actions after that in the redirected page from the login file I need to do actions in registration file, so it all should happen without closing browser one after another, please help me to find a solution for this

I want to run all pytest files without closing the browser as a continuous process in a single window

Comment: Best practice for tests is to run them silo'd. Each test should start a new/clean browser, test one thing, quit browser. That also allows for parallel execution to speed the suite run time and prevents previously failed tests from affecting tests that run later.